# Defining a SparseArray functions in Mathematica 13

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions, sparse-arrays, version-13

I am defining a sparse array as a function of argument x, i.e.

```
f[x_] = SparseArray[{1->x}, {3}]
```

In Mathematica 12 this works perfectly, I can pass arguments and they will be substituted to the array. For example,

```
f[1]
```

returns a sparse array with 1 at its first element. However, in Mathematica 13 the passed argument is ignored: the first element is allways x. Is it a bug?

Here is a screenshot for v12:

[image]

And for v13:

[image]

Comment: I believe this is an intentional change. Just use SetDelayed instead of Set.

Comment: Not good, as it broke backwards compatibility -- I will have to rewrite the whole program. Also, as I understand, SetDelayed will bring performance penalty because the arrays will be recalculated each time (I actually use `f[x_] = SparseArray[Table[...]]`).

Comment: `SparseArray` is an atomic expression. That means that there are no guarantees about the behaviour in such a situation. While this kind of thing should definitely be better documented, I would not blame Wolfram for the change. Relying on this behaviour was taking a big risk.

Comment: I would consider this a bug to be reported to WR. It is certainly confusing and unexpected behavior. @Szabolcs, talking about atomicity in this context is fairly esoteric and WR has in the past gone out of their way to mask such unexpected pitfalls; why not here?

Comment: @Roman Given that Carl Woll says that he believes that this was an intentional change, and he works for Wolfram, I suspect that it is not a bug.

Comment: "Atomic" means that it doesn't _really_ have parts, even if it appears so. The `x` symbol is not part of a `SparseArray` in the same way that it would be a part of a compound expression, such as a `List`. It's no surprise that it won't be interpreted as a pattern name. Personally, I would not have relied on this behaviour, even though I do rely on undocumented functionality when it seems necessary. This seems more risky to me, than long-standing undocumented functions.

Comment: [1 / 2] I will join Szabolcs here: in this context, being atomic for an object means that it may break variable bindings at will. Once an object is evaluated, any bound variables inside it (like `x` here) may lose their bindings and therefore will not be affected in subsequent function calls with different concrete values of `x` passed. Same happens also with associations, for example. `SetDelayed` works for a different reason: the new rule created by it contains atomic / raw object constructor on the r.h.s., rather than a fully formed object. Constructors may look the same syntactically, ...

Comment: [ 2 / 2 ] ... but they, in contrast to fully formed raw objects (which live in the kernel and only imitate their `FullForm`), are actually normal expressions and obey more usual rules. In particular, the variable bindings are kept intact, just as for any normal expression. I have discussed this problem in slightly different context in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238880/whats-the-difference-between-these-2-associations/238909#238909), but actually this particular behavior may need a dedicated answer.